# Google big query connecting with PowerBI error

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi

I was working in the powerBI desktop this morning with datasets connected from Google Big Query. Unfortunately my session got locked so i had to force a quit via task manager.
After that the connection between GBQ and Powerbi is lost and i cant get access to it anymore. When trying to log in i get the following error; "Script error".... "do you want to continue running scripts on this page". Picture error:

[error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ng7uS.png)

When i just go one with the i can select my account, but in the end i can't press the allow button to accept the conditions of GBQ. [error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjXgQ.png)

Does anybody know how to solve it? I have been trying to solve this for over 2 hours now without succes.

Thanks for the help in advance!